# Formatting in android dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

If in java console it's easy just use printf, but I'm new to android, how to create column to align those strings inside the dialog?

example :

```
public void onAlert() {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setTitle("Completed! Workout log: ")
                .setMessage("Date: " + date + "\n" +
                    "Item : " + item + "\n" +
                    "Price: " + price + "\n" +
                    "Value: " + value + "\n")

                 .setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                       public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

           }
       })
       .show();
```

I would like to achieve this :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Option A (dirty) : get the alert text view and set a fixed size font

Option B (clean) : use a custom view and a tablelayout (see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomLayout )

Comment: thanks! can I ask a newbie question? what does the setView do?

Comment: (First line of the link i posted), "add [a layout] to an AlertDialog"